# More formal way to say "check in with"

Tags: synonyms

At my company we have an internal document that describes the processes we use for accomplishing a certain task. In this document we use the phrase:

> Periodically check in with ... to assess progress on ...

I have been tasked with turning this internal document into something that can be shared with our customers and stakeholders.

I'm trying to reword "check in with" so it sounds less informal, but am drawing a blank. What's a good replacement for "check in with?"

Comment: What did a thesaurus say? "meet" is probably what you want, it's the most neutral of all. Since you used the word 'stakeholders', you may be open to the managementese 'liaise'.

Comment: @Mitch - thesaurus.com doesn't have an entry for "check in with." I'm thinking of using a word like "engage."

Comment: Periodically confer with?

Comment: What's wrong with *check with* (omitting "*in*")?

Comment: Periodically consult with?

Comment: *Status update(s)*.  If you need a verb: *provide*.

Comment: @aparente001 - that is a perfect suggestion, thanks! Did you want to submit it as the answer so I can mark it as such?

Comment: It’s not clear whether the “doer” is checking in with the customer, or the customer is checking in with the “doer”.  This is because the “doer” does not usually “assess” progress, they “report” it.  The manager or customer “assesses” progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *request, ask for,* or *provide* a

**status update**

I'm not sure how to document this.  It's a phrase I've found useful when collaborating with people, especially for niggling them to make progress, or report their progress.  For example, the subject line can say, "Status update?" and the body of the email can say, for example, "Let's put something on the calendar this week for a status update."

Answer (score 0):

Check-in is a colloquial term for several different actions of at least two different actions. 
 It could mean

> providing status reports

or

> Submitting to oversight

.